# How to refer to the work you are presenting in a scientific paper?

Tags: writing, writing-style

I am co-authoring a scientific paper. In the related works section, we discussed how our work addresses some of the limitations not evaluated in the literature.

To keep style more formal, we structured the sentences to be impersonal when referring to the work we were presenting: "In this work", "In this paper" and NOT "in our work" etc...
One of my colleagues used the form "in the present work" a lot.

One of the reviewers asked to discuss the limitations addressed by our work more, so I am afraid that "in the present work" was understood as a reference to the literature instead of to our work. I'm not a native speaker, so I don't know if this could be the case.

Do you think "in the present work" is a correct way to express the concept in English? Are there other ways I didn't think about to avoid always using "in this ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your usage is fine. But I think the reviewer is just suggesting that "the present work" doesn't sufficiently place itself in the larger context of the field.

You probably need to say more, probably in the introduction, how this work "fits", and why the current state of the literature has gaps that you fill with "this work" or similar.

I doubt that the reviewer thought that "the present work" was a reference to the larger body of work in the field